# Assembly Language homework, writeheader function that makes calls to an Integer to ASCII function

Tags: c++, linux, assembly

I am taking a class where we are programming in assembly language. We've just started so I am really new to this and am having a hard time following. We are using a linux x64 system and I believe the assembler is called nasm. All I know is that I type $ nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf filename.asm into the command prompt thing to assemble.

Here is code given to me, its a function that converts and integer into its ascii value.

itoa.asm

```
; itoa: convert a non-negative integer to ascii (text)
; itoa(buffer, n) -> # bytes written

global itoa

section .text

itoa:
            mov rax, rsi
            mov rsi, 0
            mov r10, 10

.loop:
            mov rdx, 0
            div r10
            add rdx, '0'
            mov [rdi + rsi], dl
            inc rsi
            cmp rax, 0
            jg .loop

            mov rdx, rdi
            lea rcx, [rdi + rsi -1]
            jmp .reversetest

.reverseloop:
            mov al, [rdx]
            mov ah, [rcx]
            mov [rcx], al
            mov [rdx], ah
            inc rdx
            dec rcx

.reversetest:
            cmp rdx, rcx
            jl .reverseloop

            mov rax, rsi
            ret
```

Here is the instructions

WRITEHEADER

Write an assembly language function to write the header for a PPM file to a buffer. More information about PPM files is available here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format
For this function, the important part is the header, which has a simple format:

```
P3
xsize ysize
colormax
```

The “P3” is hard-coded, and signals the format in use (this is called a magic value). The xsize and ysize values are integers written out as plain text, and indicate the size of the image in pixels. The colormax value tells the maximum color value for each color channel (red, green, and blue), and is hard-coded at 255 for our purposes.

For a 1024×768 image, the header would be:

```
P3
1024 768
255
```

Which is the string: "P3\n1024 768\n255\n"

Your job is to write that header into a buffer, and return the number of bytes written.

Registers

Functions must not disturb the following registers:

- rbx, rbp, rsp, r12, r13, r14, r15

If you need to use any of those, you should push them onto the stack at the beginning of the function, and pop them back off the stack before returning. Other functions will all follow these same rules.

Your implementation of writeHeader will make calls to itoa. Any registers other than those on the list above may be destroyed in the call to itoa. Since you need to preserve some register values across the call, you must save them somewhere before making the call. The simplest way to do this is to pick a few of the caller-saved registers (those listed above) and use them. At the beginning of your function, save the old values:

```
push r13
push r14
push r15
```

Then you may use those registers in your function freely, assuming that itoa will preserve them. At the end of your function, right before returning, restore these registers from the stack:

```
pop r15
pop r14
pop r13
```

Note that the pops must happen in the reverse of the order in which the pushes occurred.

Here is the file I am to write my function in, there is some code given me already in the file

writeheader.asm

```
; writeHeader(buffer, x, y) -> # bytes written
; writes a .ppm file header to the buffer, and returns the
; number of bytes written. The maximum color value is hard-coded
; at 255, but the x and y sizes can be any non-negative integers.
;
; example: writeHeader(buffer, 100, 50) writes
; "P3\n100 50\n255\n" to the buffer and returns 14.

global writeHeader
extern itoa
```

Here is a c++ file that tests the code

test_writeheader.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

extern "C" int writeHeader(char *buffer, int x, int y);

TEST(writeHeader, all) {
    char buff[100];

    int n = writeHeader(buff, 0, 0);
    buff[n] = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(strlen(buff), n);
    EXPECT_STREQ("P3\n0 0\n255\n", buff);

    n = writeHeader(buff, 1, 2);
    buff[n] = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(strlen(buff), n);
    EXPECT_STREQ("P3\n1 2\n255\n", buff);

    n = writeHeader(buff, 1024, 768);
    buff[n] = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(strlen(buff), n);
    EXPECT_STREQ("P3\n1024 768\n255\n", buff);

    n = writeHeader(buff, 2560, 1440);
    buff[n] = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(strlen(buff), n);
    EXPECT_STREQ("P3\n2560 1440\n255\n", buff);
}
```

I know I'm not supposed to ask for people to write my code, however I am stuck and really could use some help. If you would rather write the sudo code on how to do it, I am sure I could figure the rest out.

Comment: To verify your assembly code, write the equivalent code in C++.  Tell the compiler to generate an assembly language listing of the function.  You can compare your assembly to the code generated by the compiler.

Comment: BTW, assembly language is processor specific.  For example, the assembly language you posted will not work on an ARM7 processor or an 8051.